# Obtener registro anterior

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta tabla con estos datos (nombre y apellidos de actores)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La web tiene que mostrar los datos (nombre y apellidos) de un actor y tengo dos botones (anterior y siguiente) para consultar el actor anterior o el siguiente

Tengo la consulta de esta manera:

```
SELECT id_ac, nombre, apellidos FROM actores WHERE nombre < (SELECT nombre FROM actores WHERE id_ac = 408) ORDER BY nombre DESC LIMIT 1
```

Entonces, si hago una prueba para obtener el registro anterior correspondiente al actor con id 408, obtengo como resultado Albert con id 49, en lugar de Alberto con id 489 que sería justo el anterior, ya que hay más de un actor llamado Alberto

Cómo puedo hacer la consulta?

Gracias!

Comment: Y si en ves de poner `<` pones `<=` ?

Comment: Y es correcto.. si queres obtener el id anterior, deberias ordenar por id tambien...

Comment: Si pongo <= obtengo el mismo registro, el que tiene id 408 y no el anterior que es el que tiene id 489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienen el mismo nombre debes traer los de menor apellido, además de excluir el id de referencia:

```
SELECT a.id_ac, a.nombre, a.apellidos 
  FROM actores a
    INNER JOIN actores ar
      ON    ar.id_ac = 408
        AND (   ar.nombre > a.nombre
             OR (    ar.nombre = a.nombre
                 AND ar.apellidos > a.apellidos
                )
            )
        AND ar.id_ac <> a.id_ac
  ORDER BY a.nombre DESC, a.apellidos DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Es un *self-join*, donde `ar` es para el actor de referencia.

Comment: ¿Excluir el id de referencia lo haces con esto?... AND ar.id_ac <> a.id_ac... He comprobado que omitiendo esa línea el resultado es el mismo. Gracias!

Comment: @Juaqui : Así es, prácticamente sólo sirve para homónimos.

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo que recurras a un campo en el mantengas actualizado el orden, si lees más de lo que escribes, que suele ser lo habitual, apenas te afectará al rendimiento:

```
ALTER TABLE actores ADD orden int;
```

Cada vez que realices un `INSERT`, `DELETE` o `UPDATE` en esa tabla, deberías actualizar el contenido de ese campo con estas dos instrucciones que debes ejecutar dentro de la misma sesión, desde un disparador o desde el programa que lances la consulta de alta, baja o modificación.

```
set @i=0;
UPDATE actores JOIN (
    SELECT id_ac,@i:=@i+1 orden
      FROM actores
      ORDER BY nombre,apellidos
  ) c1 USING(id_ac)
  SET actores.orden=c1.orden;
```

Como si se tratara de una consulta de tipo `SELECT`, con un `UPDATE` también puedes hacer uso del `JOIN` que, en este caso, combina la tabla `actores` con una versión ordenada de sí misma. Si la ejecutas por separado, verás qué contiene exactamente:

```
set @i=0;
SELECT id_ac,@i:=@i+1 orden
   FROM actores
   ORDER BY nombre,apellidos;
```

La palabra reservada `SET` forma parte del `UPDATE`. Estará más habituado a verlo así:

```
UPDATE tabla SET campo='valor' WHERE id=4;
```

De esta forma te resultará muy fácil localizar tanto al anterior como al siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM actores
  WHERE orden=(
    SELECT orden-1 FROM actores
      WHERE id_ac=408
  );
```

Las pruebas las he realizado con este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE actores(
  id_ac int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(63),
  apellidos varchar(63),
  cumple date
  );

INSERT INTO actores (id_ac, nombre, apellidos) VALUES
(49,'Albert','Brooks'),(489,'Alberto','Ammann'),(408,'Alberto','Ferreiro');
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Vale, se está modificando la tabla y añadiendo un campo para guardar el orden, me falta entender cómo lo hace pero entiendo el propósito... Pero qué pasa si voy añadiendo actores nuevos? Los registros nuevos que añado a la BD se quedan con el campo orden en NULL y ya no puedo localizar al anterior ni siguiente...

Comment: Podrías explicarme esta línea: c1 USING(id_ac)... y esta otra: SET actores.orden=c1.orden;... es lo que no termino de entender. Gracias!

Comment: Amplío la respuesta incluyendo las aclaraciones que solicitas

Answer (score 0):

Así como lo comenta David, es necesario que tengas un identificador por fila para que te sea más fácil calcular el anterior o el siguiente.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by nombre desc) AS Orden, id_ac, nombre, apellidos FROM actores
```

...con algo así puedes saber en que registro estás y a cual vas.

Comment: Sería conveniente aclararle al OP que `row_number` existe desde MySQL 8 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: Si claro, sería importante entonces saber que versión de SQL usa él para de allí partir. La versión que yo uso es la 2008 R2 y ya trae esa función, por eso lo comenté pues a mi me funcionó. Gracias